# Can I load a file in PHP as a string with inline variables?

Tags: php

I've got a simple (but not tiny) template for some HTML, complete with inline variables. I'd like to pull that out as a separate file, and have the ability to switch in other template files. Is there a way to load a file into a string, but have it process inline variables?

Eg:

```
$thing="complete sentence";
$test=<<<END
    This will get parsed as a $thing.
END;
echo $test; // This will get parsed as a complete sentence.
```

What I want is something like this:

```
// "test.html"
<html>
<body>
    <p>This will get parsed as a $thing.</p>
</body>

// "index.php"
$thing="complete sentence";
$test=file_get_contents("test.html");
echo $test; // This will get parsed as a complete sentence.
```

How do I achieve this, preferably without a templating library?

Comment: +1, but is there any particular reason you want to avoid a library?

Comment: Something wrong with `include`?

Comment: @tandu - My original idea was just to have an HTML file (which for some reason I didn't specify), which validated by itself - so I couldn't load it all into a variable in the template file, which I assume I'd need for `include`

@Levi, I guess I just think that a library is adding complexity that I hope I don't need.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can use `include` to simply load the file as if it were part of the calling code.

```
include("included_file.php");
```

If you cannot `include` for some reason, you can read the file contents and `eval` it.

```
$content = file_get_contents("included_file.php");
eval($content);
```

**UPDATE:**

As pointed by NikiC, your file test.html doesn't have valid PHP. You would have to change it so `include` can work. Your test.html should have this content:

```
<html>
<body>
    <p>This will get parsed as a <?= $thing ?>.</p>
</body>
```

And `eval` would not work with this code, as this is not pure PHP code, it is HTML code with PHP inside it. If your included file has just PHP code, it would work fine.

Comment: I can't bring myself to upvote any answer involving eval(), even if the rest of the answer is 100% correct...

Comment: I myself agree that eval is not a beautiful solution on most cases. In this case, it looks like a typical include is a viable solution.

Comment: Can someone tell me what's wrong with `eval`? I guess it's ugly in principle, but I can't really figure out … why. It seems, in this case, to be my best bet.

Comment: @Ben: it's "ok" if used by someone knowledgeable, but it's abused way too much by the ignorant unwashed masses, who then wonder why something's broken. I'm fairly good with PHP and still consider myself part of the ignorant unwashed masses when it comes around to eval().

Comment: This will not work. PHP will not handle the contents of included files as encapsed strings, but as normal HTML (so no variable replacement). The eval example will just give you a syntax error, as the files contents aren't valid PHP.

Comment: I pulled it into a variable, so it looked more like `eval("$test=\"".str_replace('"','\"',$test)."\";");` and then the `test.html` file used `{$thing}` – I didn't even notice the inaccuracies in the original post. How crappy is my solution? Tell me.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    $thing="complete sentence";
    $test=file_get_contents("test.php");

    echo preg_replace_callback('#\$([a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*)#','changeVariables',$test);

    function changeVariables($matches)
    {
        return $GLOBALS[$matches[1]];
    }
```

This code uses `preg_replace_callback` to check what is variable. But, because we are in `function`, we cannot directly access script variables. We have to use `$_GLOBALS` variable which contains every script variable. `$matches[1]` contains name of matched variable.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work...

```
// "test.php"
This will get parsed as a %s.

// "index.php"
$thing="complete sentence";
$test=file_get_contents("test.php");
printf($test, $thing);
```

Comment: An interesting solution, but I need dynamic variables. I don't want to have to predict what variables are getting used in `$test`, and it's going to be more than one, so simply declaring the one variable ahead of time isn't going to do the trick. My example was just a simplification of what I need to accomplish. But thanks!